# Missing Token when creating Twilio Subaccount

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

How do you get a new Twilio Subaccount Token via PHP REST API?

[Twilio Rest Subaccount Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts)

I'm moving a Twilio number to a Subaccount vis PHP REST API.

I was able to create the subaccount and move the number to the new subaccount.

But then when I went to test the number, realized that even thru the Twilio documents say to use the Subaccount's Token, nowhere in that section does it should you how to get the token, nor is it returned during the creation of the subaccount.

To verify that my code was ok, I was able to login thru their website and find the token there and verify that it worked. But we need to make this an automated process thru the API.

Does anyone know how to get the subaccount token after you create it?

Comment: You should be able to use the subaccounts account SID along with the parent accounts auth token to authenticate.

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work, got error:
[HTTP 401] Unable to create record: Authenticate

Comment: ah.right.  My bad.  You auth with the parent accounts sid/token but use the subaccounts account sid in the URL you're making the request to.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out what I was doing wrong.

```
$subAccount->auth_token;
```

Should have been:

```
$subAccount->authToken
```

Here is the working code:

```
$client = new Client($masterSID, $masterToken);
$subAccount = $client->api->accounts->create(array(
        'FriendlyName' => 'NewSubAccount'
));
$subAccountSID   = $subAccount->sid;
$subAccountToken = $subAccount->authToken;
```

Comment: Where is From Number ?

Comment: There is not "From Numer"

`Subaccounts in Twilio are just accounts that are "owned" by your account. Using a subaccount, you can segment each of your customers' use of Twilio and keep it separate from all the rest. This will allow you to easily manage the activity and resources of each customer independently.`

[https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/subaccounts]

Once you have a SubAccount, you can get a Twilio Number that you can Call/SMS/MMS etc. these actions will have a "From Number" 

Hope that helps.